# Unit testing Angular 2 authGuard; spy method is not being called

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

I'm trying to unit test my auth guard service. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40301110/2800116) I was able to get this far, but now when I run the unit test for this, it says `Expected spy navigate to have been called`.

How to I get my spied router to be used as `this.router` in the service?

#### auth-guard.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  public canActivate() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    const tokenExp = localStorage.getItem('auth-token-exp');
    const hasAuth = (authToken && tokenExp);

    if(hasAuth && Date.now() < +tokenExp){
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### auth-guard.service.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';

describe('AuthGuardService', () => {
  let service:AuthGuardService = null;
  let router = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuardService,
        {provide:RouterTestingModule, useValue:router}
      ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([AuthGuardService], (agService:AuthGuardService) => {
    service = agService;
  }));

  it('checks if a user is valid', () => {
    expect(service.canActivate()).toBeFalsy();
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Replacing `RouterTestingModule` with `Router` like in the example answer throws `Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'`.

Comment: RouterTestingModule is a module, not a provider. If it is defined as a provider, nothing happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of stubbing `Router`, use dependency injection and spy on the `router.navigate()` method:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';

describe('AuthGuardService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [AuthGuardService],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    });
  });

  it('checks if a user is valid',

    // inject your guard service AND Router
    async(inject([AuthGuardService, Router], (auth, router) => {

      // add a spy
      spyOn(router, 'navigate');

      expect(auth.canActivate()).toBeFalsy();
      expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  ));
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/GNjeJSQJkoelIa9AqqPp?p=preview

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! A simple solution. Thanks very much, kind Sir!

Comment: This is way better than other guard examples I have found @stealththeninja thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For this test, you can use the ReflectiveInjector to resolve and create your auth-gaurd service object with dependencies.

But instead of passing the actual Router dependency, provide your own Router class (RouterStub) that has a navigate function. Then spy on the injected Stub to check if navigate was called.

```js
import {AuthGuardService} from './auth-guard.service';
import {ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

describe('AuthGuardService', () => {
    let service;
    let router;
    beforeEach(() => {
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
            AuthGuardService,
            {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}
        ]);
        service = injector.get(AuthGuardService);
        router = injector.get(Router);
    });

    it('checks if a user is valid', () => {
        let spyNavigation = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
        expect(service.canActivate()).toBeFalsy();
        expect(spyNavigation).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(spyNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login']);
    });
});

class RouterStub {
        navigate(routes: string[]) {
             //do nothing
        }
}
```