# How to do unit testing for getCurrentNavigation().extras.state in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular7-router

I am trying to write unit test for getCurrentNavigation().extras.state using jasmine.

To solve the issue, I have tried to spy this router method.

My component file,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-location-list',
  templateUrl: './location-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./location-list.component.scss']
})
export class LocationListComponent implements OnInit{

  locationId;
  locationName;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      this.locationId = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.locationId;
    }
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      this.locationName = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.locationName;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

My Spec file,

```
describe('LocationListComponent ', () => {
  let component: LocationListComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LocationListComponent >;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        LocationListComponent 
      ],
      providers: []
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LocationListComponent );
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(Router.prototype, 'getCurrentNavigation').and.returnValues({ 'extras': { 'state': { 'locationId': 100, 'locationName': "UK" } } });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But I'm getting the following error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. I'm using `Angular 7.2`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily do it using `stub` & `useClass` which can be reused at other `spec` files as well if you can create it in separate file and `export class RouterStub` , try:

In `spec` file create a `stub` which will have same method as `Router`:

```
class RouterStub{
 getCurrentNavigation(){
   return {
      extras: {
         state:{
           locationId: 'someId',
           locationName: 'someName'
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

and in `beforeEach()` block:

```
describe('LocationListComponent ', () => {
  let component: LocationListComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LocationListComponent >;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        LocationListComponent 
      ],
      providers: [ {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LocationListComponent );
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: With your approach will be undefined getCurrentNavigation()

Comment: How do you test it with different properties?

Comment: You need a spy on the router's `getCurrentNavigation` method in your `beforeEach` - otherwise, you will get an error of `cannot read property 'root' of undefined`. See [this post](https://newbedev.com/how-to-do-unit-testing-for-getcurrentnavigation-extras-state-in-angular-7)

Comment: Now suppose this page having ```this.router.navigate(['page-name'], navigationExtras)```
then how this will work as this need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40301110  where we can not write two time same provider.

Answer (score 20):

If we try to use both `RouterTestingModule` and `{provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}` it will throw error of `cannot read property 'root' of undefined`

So we can directly create spy for Route and return value of it

```
describe('LocationListComponent', () => {
  let component: LocationListComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LocationListComponent>;
  let router: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        LocationListComponent 
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    spyOn(router, 'getCurrentNavigation').and.returnValue({ extras: { state: { message: 'msg'} } } as any);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LocationListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I like this approach, but on the `spyOn` line it says that the argument `is not assignable to parameter of type 'Navigation': is missing the following properties from type 'Navigation': id, initialUrl, extractedUrl, trigger, previousNavigation`.

Comment: @A.Wan you can put "as any" after the object, so it will be accepted. I think this is common  way to mock partial objects in tests.

Comment: @A.Wan thanks for the issue, I have updated the answer

Comment: In my case, it does not throw the such error when I solve all issues.

Comment: Thanks for this! You can (maybe should) use `as SpyObj<Router>` vs `as any`

Comment: Hint for newer Angular versions: Use `TestBed.inject(Router);` instead of `TestBed.get(Router);`

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing for `router.getCurrentNavigation()` can be done in 3 easy steps:

1. Create mock router object:

   ```js
   const mockRouter = {
     getCurrentNavigation: jasmine.createSpy('getCurrentNavigation')
   };
   ```
2. Inject this in `providers` array:

   ```js
   providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter }]
   ```
3. Return the desired mocked value in the `beforeEach()` function

   ```js
   mockRouter.getCurrentNavigation.and.returnValue({
     extras: {
       state: {
         test: ''
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score -2):

You need to get the router instance from fixture

```
router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);
```