# Angular Jasmine test case for navigation and getCurrentNavigation not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, angular-test

My component has both `getCurrentNavigation` and `router.navigate`

I have implemented `getCurrentNavigation` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57639832/12917651)

Now page having

```
constructor() {
 if (router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      this.levelId = router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.arcadeSelectedGame;
    }
}
```

and navigation to another page

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        state: {
          dummyObject,
          gameplay_log_data,
          arcadeLevelData: this.arcadeLevelData
        }
      };
 this.router.navigate(['ad-page'], navigationExtras)
```

Now I have applied solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40301110/12917651) then navigation works but then `router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state` stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a value to implement both the cases parallels.
I have defined  `navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')` with `getCurrentNavigation`. and used `useValue` in provide in place of `useClass`.

Here is the code.

```
let mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
    getCurrentNavigation: () => {
      return {
         extras: {
            state:{
              arcadeSelectedGame: '-LAbVp7C0lTu9CV-Mgt-'
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

In Provider array

> { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter},

```
let router: Router;
```

Inside foreach

```
router = TestBed.inject(Router);
```

Test cases

```
it('Play click check navigation', async () => {
   component.playArcade();
   expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
   expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['ad-page']);
})
```